# 20.04.1 systemd stty baud rate greater then 115200 doesn't work

Tags: systemd

I am trying to configure gpsd.service to use uart with baudrate 921600.
I have put this line in the gpsd.service file:
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/stty speed 921600 -F /dev/ttyLP4

It works only with baudrates up to 115200. For bigger values the uart remians at 9600.
However after login if I put the command "stty speed 921600 -F /dev/ttyLP4" it works OK.

The status of the service looks OK:

```
systemctl status gpsd.service
��● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
nabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-01 20:23:45 EEST; 12s
 ago
TriggeredBy: ��● gpsd.socket
    Process: 4043 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/stty speed 921600 -F /dev/ttyLP4 (code=e
xited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4048 (gpsd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 5670)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
             ��└��─4048 /usr/sbin/gpsd -N -nbGN /dev/ttyLP4

Apr 01 20:23:44 rsu.grag systemd[1]: Starting GPS (Global Positioning System) Da
emon...
Apr 01 20:23:44 rsu.grag stty[4043]: 9600
Apr 01 20:23:45 rsu.grag systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) Dae
mon.
root@rsu:~# stty -F /dev/ttyLP4 speed 460800
9600
```

```
root@rsu:~# stty -F /dev/ttyLP4 speed 460800
460800
root@rsu:~# stty -F /dev/ttyLP4 speed 921600
460800
root@rsu:~# stty -F /dev/ttyLP4 speed 921600
921600
root@rsu:~#
```

If I use speeds up to 115200 it works ok.
If I use the command after login it also works with high baudrates.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards,
Giannis

Comment: Check the documentation. "931600" seems like a bogus baudrate. Will the hardware support that rate?

Comment: Yes, it supports 921600 Check the output in the first post. It accepts the setting and it works also. The problem is only with systemd. It is very strange. I looks like that something is putting back the uart in 9600 in systemd if the speed is faster than 115200.

Comment: Could you post the full content of your service file? I am surprised you use `ExecStartPre`. By the way, it is not recommended to issue commands as `root`.  Use `sudo` instead.